# How to make a button press once and then not pressable anymore?

Tags: android, button, view, android-relativelayout, imagebutton

I have a button

```
    <Button 
    android:layout_above="@id/choice2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbutton"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/q1a1"
    android:id="@+id/choice1">
</Button>
```

and when you press this button, it adds 10 to a counter/score keeper.  How do I make this button able to be pressed once, but then not pressable again after that?  Users are able to cheat and press the button multiple times to add more to there score.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in your `onCreate` method, do it like this:

```
    final Button choice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    choice1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            choice1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: other one didn't work, but this fit my purpose and worked well.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

You can either hide or disable it

```
Button mybutton;

    mybutton.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide it
    mybutton.setClickable(false); // disable the ability to click it
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button when it is pressed (in the code that is also handling the 'normal' action of the button).